# Convert raw json string in json object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Json objects can have strings, and those strings can represent another Json object. Ex:

```
{
  "foo" : "foo",
  "bar" : "{\"fizz\":\"baz\"}"
}
```

Above JSON as Java String:

```
"{ \"foo\" : \"foo\", \"bar\" : \"{\\\"fizz\\\":\\\"baz\\\"}\"}"
```

Assuming the above structure, how do I make jackson deserialize the bar property as a another POJO? Example?

```
class FooBar{
    private String foo;
    private FizzBazz bar;
}

class FizzBazz {
    private String fizz;
}
```

Comment: Annotated bar property with:
    @JsonDeserialize(convertor = FizzBazzConverter.class)

The implementation of it extends StdConvertor<String, FizzBazz> and just uses another objectMapper to convert the string to FizzBazz.

Its not a generic enough solution for my case. I can just read bar as a string and then map that to FizzBazz, but would like Jackson to do this for me in one pass. The outer json object may have many of these raw json string.

Comment: Please update your real problem with all required classes. Then it will be easy to give you an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use ObjectMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson.core **jackson-databind**

```
public void convertToPojo(){
String jsonInString="{ \"foo\" : \"foo\", \"bar\" : \"{\\\"fizz\\\":\\\"baz\\\"}\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
FooBarclsObject = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, FooBar.class);
}
```